# fresh eyes please - theme issues - jquery / select

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to give users theme options for a game. Here is what the code in the .js file looks like:

```
var clicks = 0; 
    $("#theme").on( "click", function(){
        clicks++;
        if(clicks == 1){
            var themeVal = $("#theme").val();
            var url = "url(../images/backgrounds/" + themeVal + ".jpg)";
            $("body").css('background-image', url);
            clicks = 0;
        }
    });
```

here is a short version of the html:

```
 <select id="theme">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select theme</option>
      <option value="tropical_beach">Beach</option>
      <option value="forest">Forest</option>
                     ....
</select>
```

and here is my file structure:

[image: file structure]

In console, I am not getting any errors and all the values are returning as expected....but the background is not changing when I select a new one from the drop down. I am probably overlooking something small. Your eyeballs are appreciated ;)

UPDATED:

```
var clicks = 0; 
    $("#theme").on( "change", function(){
        clicks++;
        if(clicks == 1){
            var themeVal = $("#theme").val();
            var url = "url('../images/backgrounds/" + themeVal + ".jpg')";
            $("body").css('background-image', url);
            clicks = 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: First thing. Use a `change` event for `select` instead of click. Next try using `url('...')` with quotes.

Comment: Click fires as soon aas you click on `select` and not when you select an option. The rest looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/2ttvf93r/.

Comment: okay so i took out all the click stuff and changed it to change. it looks like this now:     $("#theme").change (function(){
   var themeVal = $("#theme").val();
   var url = "url('../images/backgrounds/" + themeVal + ".jpg')";
  });

Comment: So what does not work? Any error? Are the multiple elements with ID as `#theme`? Is this dropdown added dynamically?

Comment: no it is in the html, I am not getting any errors, it is simply not changing :(

Comment: Working for me on Chrome; sample http://jsfiddle.net/2ttvf93r/1/

Comment: that's really strange. I am using chrome too and I just copy and pasted your fiddle (but changed the url) and it is not working...maybe i ned to clear my cache or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81698/discussion-between-shaunak-d-and-holymoly).

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using change event?

```
$( "#theme" ).change(function() {

});
```

Comment: thanks for your response marhs08, I have tried that and it is not working...not sure if i did it correctly, i updated my question if you want to have a peek